# custom UIButton in TableHeaderView does not respond fast compared to other buttons outside UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableView` in storyboard, and I programmatically write buttons in `UITableHeaderView`. I set up the normal and highlighted image for the button with grey color and red color, same for other outside `UITableView's` buttons.

If I touch all the buttons, the button image color would change from grey to red as expected, however, If I touch very fast, say just tap the screen and leave the screen in a very, very short time, the buttons in the header view will not change the image color. But other buttons outside table view can change the image color very fast, almost same time when I tap the screen and leave the screen.

I am confused what is going on, as the share the same code for setImage. All I can think about is that does the `UITableView` impact the button's performance? Or did I do something wrong?

Below is the code for the headverView:

```
- (void) setupProjectTableHeaderView {

    CGRect ProjectBounds = self.ProjectTableView.bounds;
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(ProjectBounds.origin.x,
                                                            ProjectBounds.origin.y,
                                                            ProjectBounds.size.width,
                                                            100)];
    UIButton *HomeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [HomeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(ProjectBounds.origin.x,
                                ProjectBounds.origin.y,
                                ProjectBounds.size.width,
                                50)];
    HomeBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 0);

    [HomeBtn setTitle:@"Home" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [HomeBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [HomeBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    HomeBtn.titleEdgeInsets  = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, 0);
    [HomeBtn setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [view addSubview:HomeBtn];    
    self.ProjectTableView.tableHeaderView = view;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a lot of search, and find out that:

```
self.ProjectTableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

is the key to solve my issue.

Seems like touch events are delayed in the UITableView, so If set this to NO, it will respond like normal buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];

headerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] init];
[btn setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.tag=section;
btn.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
```

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:btn];

```
return headerView;
```

}
-(void)sectionBtnClicked:(id)sender{

```
UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d Clicked",btn.tag] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
```

}

Comment: self.ProjectTableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;  did the trick, yours  are the same code as mine except for btn.tag=section;